# 301 redirect based on user-agent

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a domain that I want to do a wildcard 301 redirect with. All incoming traffic should do a 301 redirect if the user-agent is not a popular search engine like Google, Yahoo, Bing. 
If it is Google, Yahoo or Bing user agents, it can return a 404.

How do I do this?

Comment: ok, so? Is there a specific question? have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} googlebot|yahoobot|microsoftbot [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]

#else
Redirect 301 / http://www.somesite.com/
```

Comment: Idk why somebody downvoted my answer bellow. Do u know the reason?

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} google|bing|yahoo [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [R=404,L]
```

This will redirect any request to 404 for these user_agents.

Comment: Then just add the 301 after that?

Comment: why 301 here? i dont think you need 301 here. you want  404  for those Uagents

Comment: But I want to 301 the other user-agents as I said in the question.