# Access existing files from specifc User Agent will cause 404 error

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, user-agent, lwp-useragent

Today I check the access log of my website, and find a very strange thing.

When user accessing the file "/downloads/files/ddbfr.exe" with user agent "LWP::Simple/6.13 libwww-perl/6.13", he will get 404 error:

```
108.162.215.191 - - [22/Dec/2021:12:30:35 -0800] "GET /dbf-repair/ddbfr.exe HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "LWP::Simple/6.13 libwww-perl/6.13"
172.70.98.107 - - [22/Dec/2021:12:30:36 -0800] "HEAD /downloads/files/ddbfr.exe HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "LWP::Simple/6.13 libwww-perl/6.13"
108.162.215.191 - - [22/Dec/2021:12:30:36 -0800] "GET /dbf-repair/ddbfr.exe HTTP/1.1" 301 - "-" "LWP::Simple/6.13 libwww-perl/6.13"
172.70.98.33 - - [22/Dec/2021:12:30:37 -0800] "HEAD /downloads/files/ddbfr.exe HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "LWP::Simple/6.13 libwww-perl/6.13"
```

However, when accessing the same file "/downloads/files/ddbfr.exe" with other user agent, such as FireFox, then everything will be OK:

```
172.70.210.253 - - [22/Dec/2021:13:10:28 -0800] "GET /downloads/files/ddbfr.exe HTTP/1.1" 200 8035760 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Firefox/3.6.12"
```

It seems that my server is returned 404 for specific agent. However, I check my .htaccess file but cannot find anything like the one in [301 redirect based on user-agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34171214/301-redirect-based-on-user-agent). Why?

**Note:** There is a redirect from /dbf-repair/ddfr.exe to /downloads/files/ddbfr.exe in .htaccess.

Comment: The 404 response is also resulting from a `HEAD` request, not a `GET` request (as in your second example). Do you have mod_security, firewall, ...?

Comment: @MrWhite, There is a redirect, I have copied the full log texts, including the redirection to the original post.

Comment: "the original post" - presumably you mean `.exe` file? This redirect shouldn't make any difference. If there's nothing in your `.htaccess` file then your server config or server-side security module (mod_security, firewall, etc.) may be blocking the request.

Comment: @MrWhite, After shutting down mod_security and firewall tentatively, I finally find the issue is caused by mod_security. Thank you so much for your helps.

Comment: Just add... blocking this request can only be a good thing as this is certainly bot traffic.

Comment: @MrWhite, Thank you for hinting. My case is a bit complex. I use Cloudflare, and set the edge TTL to 14 days. Now if a bot get 404 error on a file, Cloudflare will cache the 404 for 14 days, which makes all future access to the file, even non-bot, also get 404 errors.